# Limit Yum Repo to Specific package names

Tags: centos, artifactory, nexus, rpm, yum

I am familiar with creating my own hosted yum repository on a Linux host as well as mirroring public yum repositories. What I am looking for is a solution (paid or free) that will allow me to essentially proxy the Vendor Repo (so packages can remain current) but I would only like to allow specific packages and their dependencies. For example, the repo will allow httpd but also allow users to pull bash, mailcap, shadow-utils, httpd-tools, apr, apr-util, glibc, libdb, expat, lua, pcre, libselinux, systemd-libs, zlib, systems.

Any information would be very useful. I tried limiting via the "/etc/yum.conf" file however it still has the limitation that I know all of the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can `exclude` specific packages from `yum install`, example:

```
# yum install gcc
Dependencies resolved.
===============================================================================================================
 Package                       Architecture      Version                            Repository            Size
===============================================================================================================
Installing:
 gcc                           x86_64            8.4.1-1.el8                        appstream             23 M
Installing dependencies:
 glibc-devel                   x86_64            2.28-151.el8
```

if your `/etc/yum.conf` forbids installation:

```
[main]
...
exclude=glibc-devel <--- forbid installation
```

installation fails (proving that glibc-devel was *not* installed)

```
$ sudo yum install gcc | grep error
Problem: package gcc-8.4.1-1.el8.x86_64 requires glibc-devel >= 2.2.90-12, but none of the providers can be installed
```

Comment: I tried using `include` however, the dependencies cause issues because you will have to know all of the dependencies. Using `exclude` presents the risk of allowing new packages that are added to the repo to pass and requires actively maintaining a list of thousands of entries.